# From where on the network is time information received?

Tags: clock, date-and-time

From where is the time information updated when the option `Date & time settings -> Automatic - Use network-provided values` is selected?

Is it from GSM, WiFi, GPS or anything else?

I believe it is from GSM, but I'd like to get a confirmation.

Comment: How do you know their provider is correct and not your's?  Compare it against a known accurate source, like [NIST's time service](http://time.gov/widget.html) and see if either is actually correct.

Comment: The time is set by your carrier. Have you tried unchecking the box, changing the time and then checking the box again?

Comment: The keyword is [NITZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) - that is where it comes from, certain ROM fail to handle it, others do. If it fails, can always fallback on a NTP app (this requires root BTW) :)

Comment: Good point, @t0mm13b -- if NITZ is the only source this would explain why my device is so much off per day (my provider is on the "unsupported" list). But not how it setup the date correctly and the time also rawly, initially. Is there a fall-back if NITZ is unavailable? With GPS off (I always have it off), it could only be network-based.

Comment: Can always use NTP, it happens to mine too, sometimes the clock is out a fair bit, I use [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync&hl=en) over wifi to "correct" the clock, then again my handset is rooted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [t0mm13m](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/4003/t0mm13b)'s comments:

The keyword is [NITZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) - that is where it comes from.

Certain ROMs fail to handle it, others do. If it fails, can always fallback on a NTP app like [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync&hl=en) (this requires root BTW) :)