# Phone changes timezone itself

Tags: huawei, date-and-time, time-zones

My phone is Huawei LUA-L21, here's the log from logcat:

```
D/WifiStateMachine(  876): onReceive, action:mediatek.intent.action.LOCATED_PLMN_CHANGED
E/WifiStateMachine(  876):  InitialState (when=-1ms what=131225!M_CMD_UPDATE_COUNTRY_CODE{ when=-1ms what=131225 obj=ru target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler obj=ru } 0 0
E/WifiStateMachine(  876):  DefaultState (when=-2ms what=131225!M_CMD_UPDATE_COUNTRY_CODE{ when=-2ms what=131225 obj=ru target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler obj=ru } 0 0
D/ccci_mdinit(0)(  265): save_timezone++
D/AlarmManagerService(  876): Kernel timezone updated to -180 minutes west of GMT
E/WifiStateMachine(  876):  InitialState (when=-2ms what=131152 arg1=36 arg2=1) !CMD_SET_COUNTRY_CODE 36 1 ru
E/WifiStateMachine(  876):  DefaultState (when=-3ms what=131152 arg1=36 arg2=1) !CMD_SET_COUNTRY_CODE 36 1 ru
D/Clock   ( 1137): onReceive : ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED : java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1468332368045,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Moscow,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=29,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=12,DAY_OF_YEAR=194,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=6,SECOND=8,MILLISECOND=45,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
D/Clock   ( 1137): TimeZone =libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Moscow",mRawOffset=10800000,mEarliestRawOffset=9079000,mUseDst=false,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=77]
```

Comment: While it's a good idea to include the logcat snippet, you shouldn't ommit the context: are you living in an area matching that TZ? Could it be your network provider issuing that (due to having set date/time update to automatic)? Anything else that could be relevant?

Comment: I'm living in GMT+7, it automatically changes to GMT+3 (main timezone for my country). It keeps changing when auto-tz/date both enabled and disabled.

Comment: That's almost what I've thought. So it's most likely your provider not differentiating between the TZs in your country (maybe having a bug in his system), see [Where time information is received from the network?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43386/16575)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by creating small application which restores timezone every time it changes.

GitHub: https://github.com/4ndv/tzfixer

APK: https://github.com/4ndv/tzfixer/releases/